# When I SaveAs to CSV it changes true/false to TRUE/FALSE

Tags: excel, vba, csv, boolean

I have true/false values in an xlsm formatted as TEXT.  When I SaveAS the sheet as a CSV file it changes all of the values as a TRUE/FALSE.  Is there a way to prevent that from happening, or will there need to be more steps added to the script to open the CSV and change the values to lower case?

Comment: You can try using the import wizard which should allow you to set the column again as text before the import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a CSV file, it removes formatting, so the true & false, which Excel **does** recognize like it recognizes numbers like 1, 45 etc gets changed to TRUE & FALSE.

Just for interest, this shows multiplying by TRUE and FALSE, which excel equates to 1 (true) and 0 (false), (cells B1 and B2 contain 2):

[image]

Edit based on Peh's comment:

**But note that in VBA True is -1 while in formulas True is 1**

So,if you plan something on a worksheet to use in vba,then be careful.

Comment: But note that in VBA `True` is `-1` while in formulas `True` is `1`!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you  are kidding I hope? :) Wow, that's not funny - That can really destroy logic that you plan out on a worksheet... I will edit that into the answer because it could make a big difference for someone.

Comment: @SolarMike No, I'm not kidding. Test `Debug.Print cInt(True)`. But there is an easy solution: `False` is defined to be `0` and anything else should be considered as `True`, so no need to think about `-1` or `1`. Just think about `True` being not `0` as definition.